# Regex to strip some lines out of a text file

Tags: php, regex

I need to try and strip out lines in a text file that match a pattern something like this:

`anything SEARCHTEXT;anything;anything`

where SEARCHTEXT will always be a static value and each line ends with a line break. Any chance someone could help with the regext for this please? Or give me some ideas on where to start (been to many years since I looked at regex).

I am planning on using PHP's preg_replace() for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Enable multiline and match on `^.*SEARCHTEXT;.*;.*$` - Providing that SEARCHTEXT does not contain characters which have meaning to RegEx...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution removes all lines in `$text` which contain the sub-string `SEARCHTEXT`:

```php
$text = preg_replace('/^.*?SEARCHTEXT.*\n?/m', '', $text);
```

My benchmark tests indicate that this solution is more than 10 times faster than `'/\n?.*SEARCHTEXT.*$/m'` (and this one correctly handles the case where the first line matches and the second one doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to match the whole line like so:

```
^.*SEARCHTEXT.*$
```

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) would be a good option for this.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\n?.*SEARCHTEXT.*$/m', '', $str);
```

The `\n` escape matches the line break for the matched line. This way matched lines are removed and the replace method does not just leave empty lines in the string.

The `/m` flag makes the caret (`^`) match the start of each line instead of the start of the string.

Comment: Was just about to say this didn't work then you edited it with the slashes. Perfect, thanks! Will mark as answer when I am allowed to :)

Comment: One Question: Is there a way to run this on the whole file rather than looping through each line and running it individually? Like a preg_match_all but with replace?

Comment: Glad to help! I just realized that this only empties the lines and doesn't actually remove them as you specified. I'll update the regex to remove the empty line as well.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to loop through lines with this. Just run `preg_replace` on the entire string and it will be applied to all lines (unless you provide the fourth `$limit` parameter).

Comment: Spot on, thanks! How intensive is this? Does it add quite a lot of overhead for about 200 lines where say 50 could match?

Comment: The latest expression: `/\n?.*SEARCHTEXT.*$/m` fails to remove one linefeed if the first line in the file matches and the second one doesn't. Also, this expression is quite inefficient. (Removing the `^` anchor was a bad move.) It is much more efficient to place the `\n?` at the end of the expression and keep the `^` (see my answer.)